# Using pre-C99 syntax in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, syntax, ide

I'm working with a rather old codebase, and it's all pre-C99. Therefore, there is no `bool` type, but rather a `BOOLEAN` enum. I'm a young gun, so I like VS 2010, but it's not playing particularly well with the old codebase. I guess it's using MSVC2010 to do its in-line error highlighting, and I'm also guessing <strike>MSVC2010 conforms to the C99 standard</strike>. I could be wrong about this, but in any case, it highlights "errors" when I assign BOOLEAN variables with a boolean expression. I'll give a simple example:

```
typedef enum boolean_tag {FALSE, TRUE} BOOLEAN;
BOOLEAN test = FALSE;
test = 1 == 1;
```

In the VS2010 editor, the `=` would be error-highlighted, and on mouseover will note that a value of type `bool` cannot be assigned to an entity of type `BOOLEAN`. Since pre-C99 has no concept of a `bool`, this should simply be an assignment of enum values, and therefore not an error.

So, my question is: is there a way to tell VS2010 to use pre-C99 syntax/error-checking? Or alternatively, and this is a stretch, have it use another compiler altogether for these functions?

Thanks.

EDIT: Corrected MSVC2010 assumption

Comment: Even if the editor signals this as an error, does it compile? The editor uses a _different_ parser than the actual compiler.

Comment: The Windows API uses `#define TRUE 1`.  Maybe that is messing with the code highlighter?  I've learned to ignore most highlited `=` signs when reading C code in MSVC.

Comment: The microsoft compiler does not support C99, and Microsoft has made clear that they have no intention of changing that. It looks as though VS is using C++ mode.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg
I'm using gcc for compilation. I'm just using VS because I like the features and I'm familiar with it. I'm trying to make its syntax/error highlighting as close to what gcc will compile as possible, at least on the surface.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer
Ok, that makes sense. Is there a way to change VS into a C-only mode?

Comment: I suppose there is. Probably somewhere under "Project settings" or a similarly named tab. But I've never worked with VS, so I can only guess.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384838.aspx: 

"By default, the Visual C++ compiler treats all files that end in .c as C source code, and all files that end in .cpp as C++ source code. To force the compiler to treat all files as C regardless of file name extension, use the /Tc compiler option."

Comment: @Will Retracted my earlier comment. This change only temporarily resolved the issue, once the file was reloaded, the issue resurfaced :(

Comment: That's a shame, I think that @Lundin's answer highlights the issue though. Visual studio is really not a C compiler, hence the lack of support for any of the recent C standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to consider:

- Visual Studio is a C++ compiler and therefore not ideal for compiling strictly conforming C programs.
- Visual Studio does not conform well to any version of the C standard. It certainly does not follow or implement the C99 standard.
- In C++ the expression `1 == 1` evaluates to `true` of type `bool`.
- In C, any version of the standard, `1 == 1` evaluates to the value `1` of type `int`.

Visual Studio complains because you are trying to store a bool in an enum, which is not fine in C++, a language with somewhat strong typing. In the C language there are no such restrictions.

The answer to your question is: you are getting these problems because you try to compile a C program in a compiler for another programming language.

Comment: Ok, I get that. But is there any way to at least superficially treat the files as C, even on a case-by-case basis? Also, the actual compilation is done by gcc, my issue is limited to the text editor in VS

Comment: Or is there perhaps a way to create custom rules for error highlighting?

Comment: @cjm571 Is there a reason you use Visual Studio beyond the source highlighting of the IDE? If you aren't using the RAD functionality, consider getting a real C compiler instead (GCC/Mingw for example). Perhaps keep Visual Studio only as project IDE.

Comment: There a few other conveniences in VS that I like, but basically yes. Unfortunately, my employer heavily restricts our IDE options, and VS is the best one for me